# Remote Validation attribute in base Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, modelbinders, remote-validation

I have abstract model which has property that will be validated. I want to set current controller for controller parameter.So,I added my custom attribute which inherits from Remote attribute. The problem is validate attribute applies once when model binds.

```
[SimpleListRemoteValidation("ValidateName", HttpMethod = "POST", AdditionalFields = "Id,SimpleModelType")]
    public string Name { get; set; }
```

SimpleListRemoteValidation is inherited from Remote attribute

```
public class SimpleListRemoteValidationAttribute:System.Web.Mvc.RemoteAttribute
  {
    public SimpleListRemoteValidationAttribute(string action)
      : base(action, HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["controller"].ToString())
    {
    }
  }
```

There is model binds

```
@foreach (var p in Model.GetProperties())
  {
    <td>
      @Html.Editor(p.Name)
      @Html.ValidationMessage(p.Name)
    </td>
  }
```

On the first request it puts in attribute's constructor.If I go to another controller it doesn't happen.

Comment: IIRC, attribute constructors are cached, have you tried doing a rebuild, then going in reverse order to see if it is just the first hit on the constructor that is being cached?

Comment: yes,after rebuild I get it.Where is place where I can manage this cache?

Comment: tbh, i'm not sure you can, i've certainly not seen any where that it can be altered or controlled.

Comment: It seems @Html.Editor() save its state.So, it's necessary to refresh this "state".